Is there a way to map an 'ACF' custom field as a GTIN Attribute using 'Code Snippets' plugin and the 'Google Listing and Ads' plugin in WordPress
I am trying to send Google Merchant an ACF (Advanced Custom Fields Plugin) field – ‘isbn’ – and map it as the ‘GTIN’ attribute through the ‘Google Listings and Ads’ plugin in WordPress. I want to use some custom php in a Code Snippet to do this so I don't have to worry about Child Themes.
The reason I want this functionality is because my client updates their ISBN on their products with an ACF field in order for it to also get displayed on the front-end. I need to keep it simple for them so they aren’t updating the same value in multiple places.
So therefore I need a way for Google Listings and Ads to 'understand' the ACF field and map it to GTIN.
I found this article here which suggests it is possible to map custom fields to the plugin and then assign an attribute like GTIN to them.
That article tells me to use the following code:
add_filter(
'woocommerce_gla_attribute_mapping_sources_custom_attributes',
function( $values ) {
return array_merge( $values, ['isbn']);
}
);

This made the field show up in the Google plugin, but this field wasn't actually the ACF field I needed, it was just a random made up value also called - 'isbn'.
I need it to specifically be the ACF field – ‘isbn’ – so that it transmits this data to Google Merchant correctly.
Basically something like this:
add_filter(
'woocommerce_gla_attribute_mapping_sources_custom_attributes',
function( $values ) {
$variable = get_field('isbn');
return array_merge( $values, [$variable]);
}
);

Perhaps I need to push the value into this array somehow? I’m not much into php beyond the basics sorry but I have tried looking extensively for a solution to this with no avail.
Anyone have any thoughts or experience with this?
It would be much appreciated, thanks.

"I found this article here which suggests it is possible to map custom fields to the plugin" - that article talks about the "custom fields" functionality WooCommerce itself provides - that is something different, than ACF. That is why the hook you are using, is only adding a field name to the array - so that the custom field of that name can then be selected as a data source. Directly returning a value at this point, would make no sense to begin with.

@CBroe - thanks for your reply!
I am aware it was not returning an actual ACF field and that the documentation there doesn't suggest this.
But do you think then there is a way to map an ACF field to this custom field name in order to utilise this data inside the Google Listings & Ads plugin and send it to Google Merchant Center?
Or are you saying this is a dead end for what I'm trying to achieve?

At least this hook is a dead end, I think. Adding the names of custom fields that can be selected via the UI, isn't going to help you, if your data is not actually in a custom field. As for how to make it "read" a value from an ACF field, you'd have to check what other possible hooks this plugin has to offer.
